# convert char to LPCWSTR

Tags: c, winapi

```
char lpszUsername[255];
DWORD dUsername = sizeof(lpszUsername);
GetUserNameA(lpszUsername, &dUsername);
ret_status = NetUserGetInfo(pc_name, lpszUsername, 1, (LPBYTE*)&ui);
```

So I need char for GetUserNameA, but for NetUserGetInfo - LPCWSTR.
WTF?
How do I can convert char to this?

```
error C2664: 'NetUserGetInfo' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [255]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Answer (score 2):

LPCWSTR translates to english as: "Wide-character string", or wchar_t* in C.

To convert an ascii string to a wide-character string, you may need a special conversion function.

mbstowcs() may be what you need.

Comment: technically isn't it "long pointer to wide-character string"?

Comment: "far read-only pointer to zero-terminated sequence of wide characters".  The pointer itself can be reassigned, but it can only be used to read the wide characters, not change them.  And in Win32's flat memory model there is no difference between near and far pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `GetUserNameW` instead of `GetUserNameA`.  This will give you the current user's name in a wide-character string, eliminating the need to convert from ANSI to Unicode.

```
WCHAR lpwszUsername[255];
DWORD dUsername = sizeof(lpwszUsername) / sizeof(WCHAR);
GetUserNameW(lpwszUsername, &dUsername);
ret_status = NetUserGetInfo(pc_name, lpwszUsername, 1, (LPBYTE*)&ui);
```

Comment: Even better, use `GetUserNameW` to avoid depending on a macro.

Comment: @dan, but then if Loderunner tries to compile for ANSI, this will break the opposite way (needing to convert a wide-character string to an ANSI string).  What's wrong with depending on a macro?  It's a well-documented part of the Windows API, and extremely unlikely to change.

Comment: @dan, ah, nevermind.  I missed the part that NetUserGetInfo only has a wide-character version.  Editing...

Answer (score 0):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28VS.80%29.aspx) for the relevant conversion macros:

```
#include <AtlBase.h>

USES_CONVERSION;

char lpszUsername[255];
DWORD dUsername = sizeof(lpszUsername);
GetUserNameA(lpszUsername, &dUsername);

// A2W() should do it
ret_status = NetUserGetInfo(pc_name, A2W(lpszUsername), 1, (LPBYTE*)&ui);
```